# Is Vague the opposite of Vivid?

Tags: antonyms

I can say:

> - I have a **vague** memory of something.
> - I have a **vivid** memory of something.

So are they opposites?

Comment: *Vague* is listed as an antonym of *vivid* in this dictionary: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/vivid#vivid__2.

Answer (score 21):

In that **one** use (in relation to memories), it could be argued that they are.

> *I have a **vague memory** of something.*

Means I can barely remember it but I can remember it a little bit.

> *I have a **vivid memory** of something.*

Means I have a very strong, clear memory with lots of details.

---

In general, though, they are not opposites and would not be used together..

A photograph with "vivid colors" could not be compared to a photo with "vague colors"... I'm not even sure what that means. The common opposite would be "muted colors".

If you have a "vague idea" about how you're going to do something, the person who knows exactly how they are going to do it would have a "clear idea".

Comment: It may be worth noting that *clear* could be used in the OP's example instead of *vivid*, so *clear* is perhaps a more common choice for an opposite to *vague* – but *vague* isn’t the sort of thing that has a distinct and defined opposite; *vague* vs. *clear* is not the same as *small* vs. *big*.

Comment: "muted colors" -- or perhaps "dull colors".

Comment: "Precise" would work as an opposite of "vague."  You could also have "specific" and maybe "exact."

Comment: If you guys have other options, feel free to answer the question yourself. The OP is not asking for what **is** the opposite, so I've chosen to primarily answer the question along with explaining that the words aren't **generally** opposites.

Answer (score 7):

*Vivid* means stimulating, bright, loud, lively.

*Vague* means "imprecise" and is usually used for describing someone's words or communication.  It isn't used to describe the visual look of something very much.  I would not call a work of art "vague", for example, unless the work of art was intended to communicate something (like a sign) and failed.

*Dull* is a better antonym of *vivid*, as it can mean things that are not stimulating, not bright, not loud, not lively, "boring", etc.

Comment: I'd recommend vague/vivid for memories, and dull/vivid for colors. And colorless/vivid for personality. And muted/vivid for contrast.

Answer (score 5):

In relation to a memory (of something), you could say that they are opposites with a measure of certainty, but there are instances in literature when the writer uses them as adjectives that do not exclude each other:

> But imagination is "merely the **vivid but vague** association of images with passion," while reason, the governing faculty of physical science, associates images "according to facts observed in nature" (Jonathan Smith, 1994)
>
> Sapir and Whorf's writings on this matter tend to be **vivid but vague**, as the following quotation from Whorf illustrates: We dissect nature along lines laid down by our native languages. (Paul Elbourne, 2011)

And especially this quote:

> My memory of the events that followed is both **vivid and vague**.  Vivid is the emotional climate - a sense of relief about the change, about being able to leave this accursed place, where we had spent almost two years - two painful, frightened, and hungry years. Vague are details of geography, of people. ([Lilka Trzcinska-Croydon, 2004](https://books.google.ru/books?id=1k-ZBAjR9DAC&lpg=PA107&dq=%22vivid%20and%20vague%22&hl=ru&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=%22vivid%20and%20vague%22&f=false))

Still, the fact that this latter writer feels the need to explain why her memory is both **vivid and vague** indicates that "a vivid memory" of something would in many (or most?) contexts be in opposition to "a vague memory" of something.

Here's another example with "memory":

> There is support of this kind for the idea that **memory** for trauma can be both exceptionally **vivid and vague** or disorganized, depending on how the study is conducted and what type of memory is targeted. ([Friedman et al., 2014](https://books.google.ru/books?id=EeSVAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA211&dq=%22vivid%20and%20vague%22&hl=ru&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q=%22vivid%20and%20vague%22&f=false))

---

One more radical antonym to **vague** with respect to **a memory (of something)** is probably **distinct**:

> Pete Doherty: 'I have **a distinct memory** of friends I had at school whose parents were, for want of a better word, bohemian.

It would be harder to say "my memory of that experience is both **distinct and vague**" compared with **vivid and vague**, IMHO.

With "vivid and vague" we can have a division of labor: a memory is "emotionally vivid" but "factually vague". But it's hard to have an "emotionally distinct" or "emotionally vague" memory, so this division of labor is less possible.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.  Vague is the opposite of vivid.  Alternatively, you can use clear instead of vivid.